# How to create a relative frequency histogram in matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics, histogram

I have a set of 100 datapoints that I have split into 10 bins and displayed as a histogram, however I would like to display it as a relative frequency histogram so I need to scale the height of each bin by 100. How do I do this?

```
M = readmatrix('Data.csv');
y= M(:,1);
histogram(y,10)
```

would it be possible to divide the resulting bins in some simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `probability` normalization,

```
histogram(y,10,'Normalization','probability')
```

See the [histogram documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) for the other normalizations available.